# Enable internet only for specific apps

Tags: internet, firewall

I will need to spend few weeks with no internet, but I will still have my mobile hot spot. So I wonder if I can prohibit all apps including OS (which I know will try silently to update something) from using internet except terminal, as I still want to be able to connect to my remote server and code.

A free (and/or native) solution would be preferred but I would settle with something I have to pay for if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [TCPBlock](http://tcpblock.wordpress.com)

> TCPBlock is a lightweight and fast application firewall ... you can prevent selected applications on your computer from opening connections to the network.

The app also includes a white list mode which seems to be what you want in this case, where all connections are blocked except the ones you define.

TCPBlock is currently free and can be downloaded [here](http://tcpblock.wordpress.com).

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: TCPBlock seems to have been discontinued an doesn't work since El Capitan. https://www.tripmode.ch/ looks like a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I think the app called [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/download.html) is right for the job.

In it you can set up who has access to Internet resources, including all not so obvious background "blood suckers", like the one checking for software updates and so on.

Comment: Yes, I just read about it. It sounds like it can do the job. Will accept if there will be no native OS solutions posted here.